# How do i delete a foreign key constraint programmatically in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, foreign-keys

How do i delete a foreign key constraint programmatically in Microsoft Access, preferable using SQL. For starters i don't know how to find the name of the foreign key.

I connect to Access from a Java application using the JDBC-ODBC bridge. I want to execute the SQL from my Java application.

I can see the relationship in Access, in the RelationShip view, but there seems to be no way of finding out the name. If i could find out the name i expect i could drop it with an ALTER TABLE statement.

Comment: Where do you wish to run the SQL?

Comment: I connect to Access from a Java application using the JDBC-ODBC bridge. I want to execute the SQL from my Java application.

Comment: I can see the relationship in Access, in the RelationShip view, but there seems to be no way of finding out the name. If i could find out the name i expect i could drop it with an ALTER TABLE statement.

Comment: I suspect you may need to use a schema to get the name cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaForeignKeys) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668760.aspx

Comment: Alter table <name> drop constraint <name>

Answer (score 6):

Determine the relationship using

> SELECT szRelationship FROM
>   Msysrelationships WHERE szObject =
>   'childtablename' and
>   szReferencedObject = 'parenttablename'

THEN

Use the ALTER TABLE command. Something along the line of this

> ALTER TABLE Table2 DROP CONSTRAINT Relation1

Answer (score 1):

I've tried accessing the foreign key name via JDBC's DataBaseMetadata object, but the JDBC-ODBC bridge does not implement the required functions. So i've resorted to droping and recreating the entire table with the foreign key.

Comment: for future reference you may want to use the following method. It works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184479/how-do-i-delete-a-foreign-key-constraint-programmatically-in-microsoft-access/3469074#3469074